# Why is my for loop not returning anything?

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop

I'm just starting to learn programming by myself and I've coded up a little program in a Jupyter notebook using Python 3.0 (Anaconda distribution) that is supposed to take in a word and return all the words in a JSON file that rhyme with your input word. I've found that when I run it I get nothing in return. I've racked my brain trying to think of what I did wrong here - I'm sure it's something stupid that I've missed.

```
import json

english_words = open('C:/Users/thoma/Documents/Programs/Python Programs/Rhyme Machine/words_dictionary.json', 'r')
rhymee = input('give me a word and ill return you all the words that rhyme with it. ')
rhymers = []

for word in english_words:
    if len(word) > 3 and word[-3:] == rhymee[-3:]:
        rhymers.append(word)
    else:
        pass
print(rhymers)
```

Comment: This depends on the format of the JSON file. Please show us an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't have `read()` function in that code so English words contain only file objects not the data. Try to read file first then do `for` loop. Play around and try to print English the word variable.

Comment: In Python, you *can* iterate over the contents of a file using a `for` loop this way, without using `read()`. The problem is that `word` will be one line from the file at a time, not one word, because the file is in JSON format and there is no code here to parse it as JSON.